# How to punctuate a sentence with, "What better way to...than to..."

Tags: punctuation, end-punctuation

It would seem that most sentences that use the format, "What better way to...than..." end in a question mark. However, a question mark just doesn't seem right for this sentence. Should this sentence end in a question mark or a period?

What better way to summarize her theory of comfort than with the words that originally inspired her passion for comfort care?

or

What better way to summarize her theory of comfort than with the words that originally inspired her passion for comfort care.